# Problems about Brahmagupta's Identity

Tags: number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $S$ be the set of all positive integers
of the form $x^2 + dy^2$
, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.

(b) Prove that if $a ∈ S$ and $p ∈ S$, such that $p$ is a prime and $p | a$,
then $a/p ∈ S$.

(c) Assume that the equation $x^2 + dy^2$ = p has a solution in nonnegative integers $x$ and $y$, where $p$ is a given prime. Show that if
$d ≥ 2$, then the solution is unique, and if $d = 1$, then there are
exactly two solutions.

I am not sure how to solve b), isn't this a direct consequence of Brahmagupta's Identity?

I tried to parallel both it with the identity

$(a^2_1 + db^2_1) (z) = (a^2_2+db^2_2)$ where $(a^2_1 + db^2_1)$ is prime

$(x^2_1+dy^2_1)(x^2_2+dy^2_2) = (x_1x_2 +dy_1y_2)^2 + d(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)$

in which I tried Equating both the RHS to get a value of z in terms of a and b, but it became very messy fast, I was wondering if this is the right approach. The prime constraint was also something I didn't know how to use

In c), I have no idea how to start the problem, I tried to do the d=1 case, where the only solutions to the equation where $(a,b$ and $ (b,a)$. I tried assuming another solution $(c,d)$

$a^2+b^2 = p$ and $ c^2+d^2 = p$

$(a+\sqrt{-b})(a-\sqrt{-b})(c+\sqrt{-d})(c-\sqrt{-d}) = p^2$

$(ac - \sqrt{bd} + \sqrt{-bd} + \sqrt{-ca})(ac - \sqrt{bd} - \sqrt{-bd} - \sqrt{-ca}) = p^2$

and then I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof of (b)**

Let $p=x^2+dy^2$ and $a=u^2+dv^2$. Then, modulo $p$,

$$dy^2u^2\equiv (-x^2)(-dv^2)\equiv dx^2v^2$$ and so $$d(yu-xv)(yu+xv)\equiv 0.$$

We can change the sign of $v$, say, so that $yu-xv\equiv 0$. Then $$pa=(xu+dyv)^2+d(yu-xv)^2.$$

$p^2$ is a factor of $pa$ and of $(yu-xv)^2$ therefore $p^2$ is also a factor of $(xu+ydv)^2$. Therefore we have the required result:- 
$$\frac{a}{p}= \left(\frac{xu+dyv}{p}\right)^2+d\left(\frac{yu-xv}{p}\right)^2.$$

**Proof of (c)**

Suppose $p=x^2+dy^2=u^2+dv^2$, where $x\ne u$ and $y\ne v$ are non-negative integers.

Then, by part (b), $$1= \left(\frac{xu\pm dyv}{p}\right)^2+d\left(\frac{yu\mp xv}{p}\right)^2.$$

**If $d\ge 2$**

Then we must have $yu=\pm xv$. Let $u=tx$, then $v=ty$ and so $p=x^2+dy^2=t^2(x^2+dy^2)$. Therefore $t^2=1$ and so the non-negative integers $u=x$ and $v=y$.

**If $d=1$**

Then we can have $xu=yv$ or $yu=xv$. The same argument therefore gives just the two solutions $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$.